# Print view in email notification

Tags: views, emails

I have created [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and that is with edit node from admin side, and I want to send same view by printing in email and I am using code to print view in email like this

```
$items['user/%user/display']['access callback'] = false;
$viewName = 'example_view_1';
print views_embed_view($viewName);
```

But there is edit node link also whenever I see from admin side,but whenever I got same view in email then it will not show edit link of node, Let me know if anyone have solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done this reminder this way.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions'); 
$submissions = webform_get_submissions(nodeid);
```

and checked roles while printing node data in loop and get edit link through `$base_url;` and print into simple tabular format. Let me know if any query in it.

Thanks for the support.